# Data from a form is not accepted, takes a passed variable as a NULL?

Tags: php, forms

I've been working on this form problem, it doesn't insert data into database and displays an error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'appID' cannot be null

I've run `var_dump` on my `$_GET['id']` and it shows it as a normal passed variable, I have no idea why the MySQL thinks it’s null.

Form:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) { ?>
<!--//include("form.php");
echo "<a href='form.php?id=".$_GET['id']."'>Add a review</a>";-->
<form method="POST"
 action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<select name="rating">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<span class="error"><?php echo $rateErr;?></span>
<br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment);?>">Enter text here...</textarea>
<span class="error"><?php echo $comErr;?></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php }
else {
echo "You need to login to review this app";
}
?>
```

And the function to validate and insert the data

```
<?php
    // define variables and initialize with empty values
    $rateErr = $comErr = "";
    $rating = $comment = "";


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if ($_POST["rating"] == "") {
            $rateErr = "Rate the app";
        }
        else {
            $rating= $_POST["rating"];
        }

        if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
            $comErr = "Missing";
        }
        else {
            $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        }
        if ($rateErr == "" && $comErr == "") {
            try {
                $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
                $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
                $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (rating, content, appID, user) VALUES (:rating, :comment, :id, :username)";

                $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
                $stmt->bindValue( ":rating", $rating);
                $stmt->bindValue( ":comment", $comment);
                $stmt->bindValue( ":id", $_GET['id']);
                $stmt->bindValue( ":username", $_SESSION['username']);
                $stmt->execute();
                return "Submitted successfully";
            }
            catch( PDOException $e ) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for this; note `POST` request method:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

But access this;  note `$_GET` request method:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_GET['id']);
```

When it should be this using `$_POST`:

```
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_POST['id']);
```

That said, you have this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

But the problem is that the `else` of that would be `GET` right? And you have a `$_GET['id']` nested in that check for `POST` right? Then why not do this:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], array('POST', 'GET')) {
```

That way your check deals with `POST` and `GET` methods. Perhaps a larger refactoring is needed for better error catching? Here is a slight refactoring you should try. I removed the database insert logic from the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` and set a `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {` which sets a `$appID` as well.

```
<?php
    // define variables and initialize with empty values
    $rateErr = $comErr = "";
    $rating = $comment = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        if ($_POST["rating"] == "") {
            $rateErr = "Rate the app";
        }
        else {
            $rating= $_POST["rating"];
        }

        if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
            $comErr = "Missing";
        }
        else {
            $comment = $_POST["comment"];
        }

    }

    $appID = $appIDErr = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
        if (empty($_GET["id"])) {
            $appIDErr = "Missing";
        }
        else {
            $appID = $_GET["id"];
        }

    }

    if ($rateErr == "" && $comErr == "" && $appIDErr == "") {
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "INSERT INTO reviews (rating, content, appID, user) VALUES (:rating, :comment, :id, :username)";

            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( ":rating", $rating);
            $stmt->bindValue( ":comment", $comment);
            $stmt->bindValue( ":id", $appID);
            $stmt->bindValue( ":username", $_SESSION['username']);
            $stmt->execute();
            return "Submitted successfully";
        }
        catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: right, I get it. That means I should implement that id to be posted with the form? I'm not sure how to solve it, i cannot simple assign it, right?

Comment: have no idea, if I change if statement to the one you posted, I get blank page not even an error :/

Comment: This one gives me a blank page, no error xD Could it be smth to do that I use $_GET['id'] in the page for smth else? but it's another query so i wouldn't think it's an issue...

Comment: I've put var_dump for POST and GET in your code after appropriate if statements and it gives me array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } which i assume is just get ID

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$_POST` request you need check variable, changed:

```
if ($rateErr == "" && $comErr == "") {
```

To

```
if (empty($rateErr) && empty($comErr) && isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
```

And replace next line, because you don't have `$_GET` request:

`$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_GET['id']);`

To

`$stmt->bindValue(":id", $_POST['id']);`

Comment: if I do that the page just reloads and shows me only the form with no other content and nothing is entered into DB. I guess i need to post that id in a variable somehow through the form or smth

Comment: It code makes the following: if you don't have or empty post request `$_POST['id']` then it don't put any data in DB because column 'appID' cannot be null in your DB. So you can check request data `var_dump($_POST)` and look into your `id`

Comment: Shows just NULL or array(0) { } if i put it in if statement

Comment: it mean you don't use `post` request, try see all of method request `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, and put this line into first line of your code

Comment: array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } which must be the id only

Comment: >I've put var_dump for **POST** and **GET** in your code after .... When you see array with `id` when you `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_GET)` ?

Comment: My bad I've it after the form is submitted and it shows Column 'appID' cannot be nullarray(3) { ["rating"]=> string(1) "2" ["comment"]=> string(5) "greta" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } and that's for REQUEST

Comment: replace all method `$_POST` in your script to `$_REQUEST`and look what happening. Delete for this time `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` and last `}`

Comment: If i do that I just get the form with errors displayed beside it

Comment: I don't know, if i try to submit the form now it gives Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'content' cannot be null

Comment: Try next code [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba824d6f4b8c38d03553733112ee3f1047bfc07f)